# data accuracy loss adding values to excel cell c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, cell, precision

Morning, I have a accuracy problem working with excel cells.

In the code below, I create an array with all my class components to make the data addition easier. All of them are strings, and I have checked that before the addition to the excel cell, the datum is correct.

```
string[] row = { bill.BillNumber, "\t", bill.ContractNumber, (more data...)};

for (int j = 1; j <= row.Length; j++)
{
    if (j - 1 == 0)
    {
        float bin = 0;
        float.TryParse(row[j - 1], out bin);
        workSheet.Cells[z, j] = bin;
    }
    else
    {
        workSheet.Cells[z, j] = row[j - 1];
    }
}
```

At the beginning I had no the if and I was adding string to string to the cells. This was the result:

```
    workSheet.Cells[z, j].value 2.01404290302382E+16    dynamic {double}
    bill.BillNumber "20140429030238239" string
```

When I change the cell format in excel, the number is turned to an approximation.
If I parse before the string this is happened:

```
    bin 2.01404288E+16  float
    workSheet.Cells[z, j].value 20140428795838464.0 dynamic {double}
    bill.BillNumber "20140429030238239" string
```

And when I do the same but with a long format, I get a very approximate result but not the exact:

```
    bin 20140429030238239   long
    workSheet.Cells[z, j].value 20140429030238240.0 dynamic {double}
    bill.BillNumber "20140429030238239" string
```

This was my first option, but like I was not getting the correct result, I tried the other two. I have no more ideas, why am I losing accuracy?

Thanks in advanced.

Greetings.

PS: I have not said that the woorksheet is an `Excel.Worksheet`

Comment: I got "a solution" but the problem is still there
`row[j - 1] = "'" + row[j - 1];
    workSheet.Cells[z, j] = row[j - 1];`

With this code I get the next:

    `workSheet.Cells[z, j].value="20140429030238239" dynamic {string} bill.BillNumber="20140429030238239" string`

but...

Comment: I think your problem is that Excel can't handle such huge numbers. Look up the limitations in VBA. What may help you is changing the .NumberFormat property of Range to TEXT so you can store it as a string not an actual number

Comment: @mehow Excel has no any problem to manage that kind of numbers because I am taking the data from another excel file. My problem is when I put the data again in my file. Anyway if you put the " ' " ahead of the string array, excel interprets it as a text and there is no round. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation of Double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double(v=vs.110).aspx):

> All floating-point numbers also have a limited number of significant digits, which also determines how accurately a floating-point value approximates a real number. **A Double value has up to 15 decimal digits of precision, although a maximum of 17 digits is maintained internally.**

*(my emphasis)*

So as long as you are converting to a floating point value, you will have limited digits available before accuracy suffers.

Excel has the same problem, it doesn't store numbers with infinite precision either and although I don't know the exact limits it operates with, I would imagine it would be close to what .NET uses as .NET uses standard types.